# How to create Laravel route only for testing (phpunit)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I want to test my parser. Is there a way to create a route and return content on, that route, - only for phpunit test?

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate file for testing routes only.

And then include these routes only in dev environment, or exclude them in production only for example...

Comment: In your `/routes/web.php` you can add conditional `if ( env('ENVIRONMENT') != 'production' ) { include_once('test_routes.php') }` and declare your test routes in this file (test_routes.php)...

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of testing is to mimic the live application functionality. (This would be Feature testing or maybe using Dusk). If you're needing to get at data that is not accessible via your regular routes, you are probably doing Unit testing (on specific classes or objects). This doesn't require routes.

Comment: I have a parser, which takes url from database, then goes to that url and parses data and saves in DB. For the testing, i would like to insert into DB my testing url, which would return some code for parser and then i could check in databse if parser parsed and saves data correctly.

Comment: So you need the initial routes to hit in your DB? Use a seeder.

Comment: No, i need route for parser curl. Route would return content for parser to parse.

Comment: But wouldn't this happen in your live site?

Comment: It needs only for development.

Comment: In your routes, use `if ( env('ENVIRONMENT') != 'production' )  { ... your routes ... }`